# How to modify groupby() in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I hope you are safe and having a good time. In the below code snippet, I am trying to create a timeline graph that depicts an overall trend. I thought of process like:

- Form a dataframe using groupby() to calculate the actual rate [check below code]
- plot the data frame using iplot()

```
actual_rate1= df.groupby(['year','disease']).std()
actual_rate1.dropna(inplace=True)
actual_rate1 = actual_rate1.reset_index('year')
```

To achieve a timeline using iplot or plt.plot(), the dataframe should contain rate and year. so I used reset_index() on the disease which worked
[Result after reset_index()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foKyM.png)

But it is also taking disease in the plot and generating the wrong graph
[needed columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxneG.png)

**The goal is: create a timeline graph on the x-axis -> year, y-axis -> rate, and hue by disease, this will generate a linechart for all 3 diseases**

One of the proposed solutions was sb.lineplot by @Daniel Da Costa threw an error
[error thrown while sns.lineplot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhMje.png)

Here is the link to data source:

> https://github.com/JordanTheDodger/Data-Visualization-using-seaborn

Comment: Could you post the code to create few rows from the DataFrame `actual_rate1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the seaborn library:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(x="year", y="rate", hue="disease", data=actual_rate1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Daniel Da Costa, unfortunately, it did not work as expected.
The error thrown is : 
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'disease'

Comment: Are you using disease as the dataFrame index? If so, try removing from the index using using actual_rate1.reset_index().

And then, try again

Comment: It worked thanks, I thought I performed that while I performed groupby. Did not verify it. The red flag was thrown when I used actualrate1.info() but I was not sure why the disease column was not appearing. Thanks again!!

Comment: don't worry! Happy to help :)